# NULL or reference existing data

Tags: database-design, database-normalization, one-to-one

I have been trying to understand this topic but I am not really getting it, its a real doubt that i am just stuck on and i am not getting anywhere without it.

I understand that it is a best practice to split up tables and keep it short, but its not really applying to my situation, for one I learned that the data that is not often being called should be split up, but these attributes are regularly being called, in my case whenever each member is loaded into the fronted his details are pulled up too.

Details about my database:

- There are 18 columns in my main table called `Member`, each column in the member table, "Individually" is only dependent on the primary key `MemberID`
- some columns have null values, and my understanding is that in MySQL NULL values aren't allocating any space

**This is where I am stuck**

Should I keep a column with null values in the `Member` table or separate it into another table and have a `MemberID` foreign key relate to it, in a one to one relationship?

For example: a person may or may not have a phone number, but a phone number must belong to one person:

```
Member (1:1)-----------(0:1) Phone number
```

`MemberId` is a foreign key and the primary key in the phone number table.

As a rule it is required in the database for a person to Input only one number that is functioning at that time, so this is not a one to many relationship

My main reason of asking this question is that the majority values in the column are null, so should I keep it in the table even though it has majority null values (of 10k records I have 4k values as NULL)

Comment: 'I Understand that it is a best practice to split up tables and keep it short' - no it isn't normalisation is the key and a table can be perfectly normalised with any number of columns.

Comment: It's quite common to see the main entities of a db to have 50 columns or more. The key aspect, is if that those properties belong to the entity. If you have a 1:N cardinality with a property it probably belongs to a different entity (table). If the cardinality is 1:1 (like phone) then it's your decision to anticipate if this cardinality will remain 1:1 in the forseeable future (keep it in the table), or if it may change to 1:N (have a separate entity).

Comment: @P.Salmon  so should I split the Tables with null values and only existing data to it or keep the column and accept null values

Comment: Storage is cheap. Accesstimes are important. Do not worry about wide tables unless you are close to the column limit. Having a 1:1 relation is useful in specific cases when a large chunk of information is optional. It is more important to have the right indexes and only query the data you need.

Comment: @TheImpaler should i follow that even though it has null values, the reason for my concern is there are 10k records and some 5k of them have null values

Comment: @PeterLembke thank you for commenting but should i keep it in the table even when the majority of the values are NULL's , I forgot to mention this in the question i will add this

Comment: My View is that phone like address is not an attribute of person in the way that gender and dob are and should be  in separate tables. This will make your code more complex and you may decide having anlaysed how your data will be used to keep in the person table to simplify code. Up to you really btw 10000 records is nothing at all.

Comment: @Newt I wouldn't worry about the disk utilization of nulls. It's a much pressing concern -- for the correct operation of the application -- to place each piece of the puzzle in the right place. The disk utilization difference is minimal; it's not the 80s anymore (when disk was expensive).

Comment: @Newt , 10K posts with 5K NULL values is very little overhead. You also have a benefit in simplicity when you query the table. Keeping things simple is always good.
Before the cell phone when a person had 0-3 numbers + fax then I would have broken out phone number to a separate table.

Answer (score 1):

There are several answers to this question,  depending on what you are really trying to do.

Sometimes, a table with a lot of NULLS in it slows down processing.  It takes a byte or two to express a NULL, and there are a few extra steps in the processing.  Sometimes, it slows things down even more to join two tables together.  The answer here is specific to your case.

Sometimes the real grief comes from SQL three valued logic.  This can be really hard to grasp, especially if you have learned two value logic since childhood.  3 is not equal to NULL.  3 is also not unequal to NULL.  And NULL is not equal to NULL. It's easy to get screwed up on this.  But if you can keep it straight,  you can write the appropriate code in views or procedures or application code.

Sometimes, it's better data management to avoid NULLS in the first place.  I've never been in this situation, and I really can't elucidate.

Sometimes, the DBMS even gets in your way.  In Oracle, a variable length character string of length zero is stored as a single zero byte.  And a NULL is also stored as a single zero byte.  If you need to keep these two distinct, you are out of luck.

One case where NULLS is almost always the right way to go is optional relationships.  In this case, the right thing is usually to have a foreign key that references the primary key of another row, usually in another table, when the relationship is present.  When the relationship is absent,  the foreign key gets a NULL.

I know this is clear as mud, but I hope it helps.